# Editing the footer of a page in Excel using a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

With Excel (Office 2010), I am printing off with the same footer, and in landscape. I made a macro which changes the workbook from Portrait to Landscape, however Excel / VB seems to not like editing the footer of a page with macros.

Are you able to edit the footer with a macro, using possibly a VB code workaround, or otherwise?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+footer&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try recording a macro? I cleaned this up, but this is directly from Excel 2003

```
Sub setFooter()

On Error GoTo HandleErrors 
'@JimmyPena pointed out an msdn example that seems useful to incorporate
Application.PrintCommunication = False 

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .LeftFooter = "What"
        .CenterFooter = "a"
        .RightFooter = "Header"

    End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True 

ExitHere: 
    Exit Sub 

HandleErrors: 
    ' If an error occurs, make sure you reset 
    ' print communications. 
    Application.PrintCommunication = True 
    Resume ExitHere 
    End Sub
```

Unless you have some other issue that I am not understanding

Comment: I did try recording the macro, however it wont record me writting in the footer. It records every thing else, however not the footer.

Comment: Sorry, I recorded in 2003 and then transferred the macro to 2010 to try it. Because I am always lost in 2010. However it still does show, when you select one of the sample footers, in the macro .RightFooter, .CenterFooter, and .LeftFooter and you could try altering those even if (and I agree recording in 2010 is poor) and isn't showing

Comment: I tired it in 2010, and it works, however its strange that it doesnt like recording it...

Comment: i personally dislike 2007-10 because they help you so much that it is more difficult

Comment: +1, but you should turn off communication with the printer to speed up access to the PageSetup Property: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Excel-2010-Communicate-cad0ff38